# non-linear systems of equations

Tags: systems-of-equations, real-numbers

How can I find all real solutions $(x, y, z)$ to the system of equations?

$xy = 2(x + y)$

$yz = 3(y + z)$

$zx = 4(z + x)$

Comment: What have you tried already? Generally people will only answer questions where the person asking has shown they have attempted to solve the problem themseelves first

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I leave some hints for you to solve for yourself.

If $x=0$ or $y=0$ or $z=0$, you get $x=y=z=0$. So, we can assume $x,y,z\neq 0$.

$$\begin{cases}\frac 1x+\frac 1y=\frac 12\\
\frac 1y+\frac 1z=\frac 13\\ 
\frac 1z+\frac 1x=\frac 14\end{cases}\implies \frac 1x+\frac 1y+\frac 1z=\frac {\frac 12+\frac 13+\frac 14}{2}=\frac {13}{24}$$

Finally, you have

$$\frac 1x=\frac {13}{24}-\frac 13=\frac {5}{24}$$

Would you like to continue from here yourself?

Comment: I did not completely solve the question, But, I just showed the possible way.  What is wrong here?

Answer (score -1):

Well, first notice that there is an obvious solution:

$$\left(x,y,z\right)=\left(0,0,0\right)\tag1$$

Now, let's solve the more difficult part. We have:

$$
\begin{cases}
xy=\alpha\left(x+y\right)\\
\\
yz=\beta\left(y+z\right)\\
\\
xz=\gamma\left(x+z\right)
\end{cases}\tag2
$$

Solving the first equation of $(2)$ for $x$ gives:

$$xy=\alpha\left(x+y\right)\space\Longleftrightarrow\space x=\frac{\alpha y}{y-\alpha}\tag3$$

Solving the second equation of $(2)$ for $y$ gives:

$$yz=\beta\left(y+z\right)\space\Longleftrightarrow\space y=\frac{\beta z}{z-\beta}\tag4$$

Solving the third equation of $(2)$ for $x$ gives:

$$xz=\gamma\left(x+z\right)\space\Longleftrightarrow\space x=\frac{\gamma z}{z-\gamma}\tag5$$

So, we can see that:

$$\frac{\beta z}{z-\beta}\cdot\frac{\alpha}{\frac{\beta z}{z-\beta}-\alpha}=\frac{\gamma z}{z-\gamma}\space\Longleftrightarrow\space z=\frac{2\alpha\beta\gamma}{\alpha\left(\beta+\gamma\right)-\beta\gamma}\tag6$$

> I'll let you finish.